# AndroidStudio refuses to acknowledge inheritance hierarchy

Tags: android, json, inheritance, kotlin

This is with `implementation 'org.json:json:20180813'`

So I have a `User` class that allows itself to be translated to a json string for persistence:

```
data class User(override val name:String, override val creds:ICredentials) : IUser, isEncodable<IUser>{
    override val isLoggedIn by lazy { creds is Credentials.Valid }

    override fun encode():String{
        val credsEncoding = creds.encode()

        return JSONStringer().withObject { it
                .key("type").value(this::class.java.name)
                .key("name").value(name)
                .key("creds").value(credsEncoding)
        }.toString()
    }
}
```

where `withObject` is an extension function:

```
fun JSONWriter.withObject(content:(JSONWriter)->JSONWriter) = content(`object`() as JSONWriter).endObject()
```

This seems to compile and work perfectly fine.

However, AndroidStudio marks it red and claims

> Unresolved reference
>
> None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch
>
> ```
> public fun JSONWriter.withObject(content:(JSONWriter)->JSONWriter):JSONWriter! defined in [...]`
> ```

If I try to "cheat" and write it as

```
(JSONStringer() as JSONWriter).withObject { it
    ...
}
```

the error becomes a warning that

> This cast can never succeed.

But apparently, it does.

Why is that? And how do I get rid of this "error"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is with implementation 'org.json:json:20180813'

That's unlikely to work well.

> Why is that?

For the past 11 years, Android has a copy of `org.json` classes in the Android SDK. [This includes `JSONStringer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer). You can't have two classes with the same fully-qualified name, and the firmware always wins. Your copy of the conflicting class will not be used, with the firmware one used instead. And the firmware's API has not changed much in those past 11 years.

> And how do I get rid of this "error"?

Remove `implementation 'org.json:json:20180813'`. Either:

- Use the Android SDK's built-in `org.json` classes, or
- Use the Android SDK's `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` classes, or
- Use a different JSON parser (e.g., Gson, Jackson, Moshi)

Comment: I actually added it specifically because AndroidStudio complained I should mock the framework for my JUnitTests. Will have to look at a different parser, then.

Comment: For true unit tests (`test/` directory), you would use `testImplementation`, not `implementation`. And you still might run into compatibility issues, if the `org.json` API has changed (I have no idea if it has or has not).